# react native React-navigation transition with effects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using the `react-navigation` library with docs here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html. I would like to transition to a new view with simple parameters, ie:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('newView', {animation: 'fade-in'})
```

However I see no `API` for this, and a google search turned up nothing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define all your custom transition effects when you initiate your navigator, not inside a screen, like in [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#modal-stacknavigator-with-custom-screen-transitions). Also, base on my understanding, transition effects are available only with stack navigator.